# Is there an Eclipse personality settings for Wing IDE?

Tags: python, eclipse, wing-ide

While PyDev turns out to be a great IDE for python, especially if you are a former Java developer accustomed to all the eclipse ubercool navigation, it still lacks some features that Wing has, like GUI for running python unit-tests.

I know Wing has some "personalities" of other editors: vi, emacs, Visual Studio, ...
Unfortunately, Eclipse is not one of them.

Before I start configuring all the keys myself, creating a keymap.eclipse file, etc. (seems like it's gonna take ages), I wanted to know if no one already configured it and can share it with the rest of the world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no Eclipse personality.

Answer (score 1):

I've added an experimental one in version 4.1.3